# Combining two navigators in React Navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have three navigators. Two of them are combined in the third main navigator.

First Navigator:

```
// Stack Navigator
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: Login,
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    ForgotPassword: ForgotPassword,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);
```

Second Navigator:

```
// Tab Navigator
const BottomNavigator =  createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    MyJobs: MyJobs,
    MyProfile: MyProfile,
    Settings: Settings,
  },
  {
    // configuration
  }
);
```

Combining Navigators:

```
// Combining Navigators
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AppStackNavigator: AppStackNavigator,
    BottomNavigator: BottomNavigator
  }
)
```

However, I am not able to pull this off. I keep on getting this error on my android emulator:

```
The component for route 'AppStackNavigator' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
AppStackNavigator: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
AppStackNavigator: MyNavigator,
}
```

I am trying to use the combined navigator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will be better to show full code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is weird, especially route config... have you looked at [react-navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) ?

try changing `YourScreenName` by `{screen: YourScreenName }`. for each of your navigators routes.

ex:

```
// Stack Navigator
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {screen: Login},
    HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
    SignUp: {screen: SignUp},
    ForgotPassword: {screen: ForgotPassword},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);
```

Comment: I tried the modified route as per your instruction but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you make that same change for every navigator ? (including your RootStack ?)

Comment: I was making a silly mistake. After trying to debug multiple ways, I realized that I was declaring RootStack before both of AppStackNavigator and BottomNavigator. LOL. Moving the Rootstack declaration at the bottom of the two other routes solved the issue.

Comment: Oh! Then the error message really didn't help. Glad you could solve it :)